# Splitting variable into equal width intervals in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to create a discrete variable, which divides a variable x into intervals of 1000. What I have is the following:

```
DATA have; 
   INPUT x; 
   DATALINES; 
1200
3200
5300
49 
6500
;
RUN;
```

What I want is something like this

```
data want;
input x y $5-14;
DATALINES; 
1200 1000-2000
3200 3000-4000
5300 5000-6000
0049 0000-1000
6500 6000-7000
; 
RUN;
```

I could of course write a data step with if else statements defining the intervals, but I have 100 of these intervals, so it would be very time consuming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `round()` function, rounding to the nearest 1000, but apply an offset of 500 first. This will give you the upper bound. Then subtract 1000 to get the lower bound.

```
data have ;
  input x ;
  upper = round(x+500,1000) ;
  lower = sum(upper,-1000) ;
  y = catx('-',put(lower,z4.),put(upper,z4.)) ;
datalines ;
1200
3200
5300
49
6500
;
run ;
```

```
   x    upper    lower        y

1200     2000     1000    1000-2000
3200     4000     3000    3000-4000
5300     6000     5000    5000-6000
  49     1000        0    0000-1000
6500     7000     6000    6000-7000
```

An alternative method would be to define a format, based on a dataset generated using a loop in 1000 increments.

Comment: Since you know how many buckets you want, proc rank does something like this, but without the formatted output.

`Proc rank data=<your data set name> out=<output data set> groups=100;/*or any number of groups wanted */`

`var growth; /* or whatever your variable is*/`

`ranks growthgroup; /* what ever variable you would like to hold the group numbers*/`

`run;`

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method to do this would be using a format, as it allows you to do analyses (such as PROC FREQ) based on the buckets, but retain the original value without having two different variables.  This is basically an extrapolation of the last sentence in Chris J's answer.  Here's the 'code' version:

```
proc format;
  value bucket1k
    0-<1000 = '< 1k'
    1000-<2000 = '1k-<2k'
    2000-<3000 = '2k-<3k'
;
quit;
```

To create this format for 100 buckets, you would do the following:

```
data for_fmt;
  retain eexcl 'Y' 
         fmtname 'bucket1k';
  format label $50.;
  do start = 0 to 99000 by 1000;
    end = start+1000;
    label = catx(' ',start,'to',end);
    output;
  end;
  if start > 99000 then do;
    hlo='o';
    start=.;
    label='MISSING';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;
```

You then use this format in any analysis that needs it (or apply it to the dataset in a data step or `PROC DATASETS`).